# How to redirect my app to login page async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mobx-react

I'm using react npm, with state management "mobx-react", all shared state in "AppStore". As the app refreshed "AppStore.signIn()" get user from localstorage and set "AppStore.signedUser", else the value is undefind.
The  component renders the user if exist,
but if not the app should redirect to "/signup" before rendering .
Because the app is rendering faster than it takes "signIn" to be completed,
it allways redirects to signup when refreshing, even though a user is exist.
how can i redirect only after the AppStore.signIn() is done?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import AppStore from './store/AppStore';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    isLogged: false,
    isCheckedLogged: false,
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await AppStore.signIn();
    if (AppStore.signedUser) {
      this.setState({ isLogged: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isLogged: false });
    }
    this.state.isCheckedLogged = true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <HashRouter>
          <nav className="main-nav">
            <NavLink exact to="/" className="nav-link">Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/signup" className="nav-link">Signup</NavLink>
          </nav>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => this.state.isLogged ?
                (<Home store={AppStore} history={HashRouter} />) :
                (<Redirect to="/signup"/>)} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" render={() =>
                (<Signup store={AppStore} history={HashRouter} />)} />
          </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
      </div>);
  }
}

export default observer(App);
```

Comment: You can conditionally show loading state till the API request completes. Also you might want to go through this [post](https://hashnode.com/post/is-good-to-use-asyncawait-in-componentwillmount-cje7gw3ce03zyiqwudv0wihvi/answer/cje7l2nsa0470iqwu8c2aeama), since it is not a good practice to have async REACT life-cycle methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a default state `loading: true` in your state. In your render function, you check if the component is loading, if it is, then you display a loader, or nothing if you like. When the `signIn()` function is done, set loading to false, and react will automatically re-render and redirect the user appropriately. HAve a look at some code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import AppStore from './store/AppStore';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    isLogged: false,
    loading: true,
    isCheckedLogged: false,
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await AppStore.signIn();
    if (AppStore.signedUser) {
      this.setState({ isLogged: true, loading: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isLogged: false, loading: false });
    }
    this.state.isCheckedLogged = true;// not sure this can help, and it's also not 
    // a right way to set state
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {! this.state.loading && (

         <HashRouter>
          <nav className="main-nav">
            <NavLink exact to="/" className="nav-link">Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/signup" className="nav-link">Signup</NavLink>
          </nav>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => this.state.isLogged ?
                (<Home store={AppStore} history={HashRouter} />) :
                (<Redirect to="/signup"/>)} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" render={() =>
                (<Signup store={AppStore} history={HashRouter} />)} />
           </Switch>
         </HashRouter>
        )}
      </div>);
  }
}

export default observer(App);
```

Comment: Great. Glad I could help. Please kindly mark as best answer so others can find the answer useful too.